# Onsen-UI list-itemを<ol><li>のような順番つきにする方法

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, cordova

Onsen-UIのリスト表示で、項目の先頭に、
HTMLの`<ol><li>`で実現されるような連番を自動で
振ることができるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Onsen UI V2のCSSでは、「・」や数字が表示されないように**list-style-type**や**list-style**を無効にしているので、CSSカウンターを使用して自前で連番を振れば実現できます。

```css
.list-item_count {
  counter-increment: item;
}
.list-item_count div::before {
  content: counter(item)".";
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/js/angular-onsenui.js"></script>
<ons-page>
  <ons-list class="list_count">
    <ons-list-item class="list-item_count">
      いぬ
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item class="list-item_count">
      ねこ
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item class="list-item_count">
      うさぎ
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```